How to Install Power ISO in Ubuntu
Hi I want to install Power ISO in Ubuntu and I don't know how to start.Can someone help me?I need this to download an iso file game.
I tried using the tar.gz file but I don't know how to open it.

You don't need third-party software to use an ISO in Linux.  Mount the file on the loopback device like so(from a terminal window):
sudo mkdir -pv /mnt/isos
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/iso/file/game.iso /mnt/isos

For the .tar.gz file, read the man page.  I'm telling the OP this now because man is the first thing others will say too use, and since tar is one of the most used applications in any Linux, man tar sounds like a great combination to start with as a new Linux user.
